# Algorithm to check a conjectural value for the rank of a large matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

Feel free to suggest a different title, I'm not sure how to phrase this. I'm in the following somewhat specific  situation:

I'm checking a conjecture which at the end of the day boils down to the computation of the rank of a large but very very sparse matrix with integer coefficients. The matrix is rectangular, of size roughly $n\times 2n$ for a somewhat scary value of $n$. Crucially, I know an upper bound $r$ for that rank, and crucially again the conjecture I'm trying to verify state that the rank is, in fact, exactly $r$. The bad news is that the conjectural $r$ is pretty close to $n$ (ie $n$ is more than a million, while $n-r$ is expected to be 34...)

> What is the cleverest algorithm to check this ?

A fairly usual trick is to work modulo some small prime $p$ since it can only decreases the rank (so that if I do find exactly $r$ I know I'm done). Another idea is that it would be enough to find, maybe randomly, $r$ linearly independent rows or columns, and if $r$ was much smaller than $n$ I think it would indeed be much more efficient than actually computing the rank, but in my situation I'm not entirely sure it would. In particular, I'm wondering if there's a known way to turn the fact that the matrix at hand is almost of maximal rank to an advantage.

Comment: How large an $n$ do you find scary? And how sparse is sparse?

Comment: $n$ is roughly 1.3 millions, and density is around 0.05. For the one I did handle by just computing the rank mod 17 using https://github.com/cbouilla/spasm, $n$ was about 600.000 and it took 40 hours. It seems for the largest one just computing the rank is gonna be tricky.

Comment: How is it represented? Is each row and column a linked list? How long would it take you to make it into upper triangular form? Is it easy to sort the rows lexicographically?  There might be algorithms almost linear in n in time if you have a good representation. Also,  how useful is an approximation (e.g. quickly showing n-r less than 100)? Gerhard "Is Not Sparse With Ideas" Paseman, 2019.09.19.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is of any help, but if you managed to find $n-r$ independent vectors in $\ker A^T$, then you would be able to conclude that the rank of $A$ is at most $r$.

Comment: Reminds me of this paper where they had to use a little bit of strategy to compute a rank of a fairly large matrix: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02029

Comment: If you flip it around to finding the size of the nullspace, it appears that linbox might have support for this, I found a mailing list entry : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linbox-use/EmgUZme8p4Y and some docs : https://linalg.org/linbox-html/examples_2rank_8_c-example.html See also this scicomp answer : https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/nullspace-algorithm-for-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @GerhardPaseman unfortunately I need an exact result.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni indeed, the bad news is my problem is the opposite one, I already know it's almost r.

Comment: @JCK My understanding is that the SPASM library I mentioned is fairly state of the art for dealing with rank computations of sparse matrices mod $p$ (eg it's supposed to do better than linbox). It's especially good at keeping the matrix sparse, but in that case on a computer with 64Gb RAM the matrix is just too big to be stored in memory. So I'm looking for a way either generic or using that extra information I have to either solve the pb directly or to reduce the size of the matrix which has to be considered.

Comment: @Adrien I'm the main developer of SpaSM. If you're still investigating the problem, you can contact me. I may be able to offer some advice. If your matrix cannot be handled by direct methods such as SpaSM, then iterative techniques (such as those Linbox offers) are the only way forward. However, the implementation is linbox is not state-of-the-art, as far as I understand.